# How to efficiently parse a string into string variables of an object

Tags: c#, stringreader

I have a string I will present in a text box that will vary somewhat but has some format to it. The string is coming from a .pdf file. It will be formatted as below:

```
1
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
LONG JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-213-703 Seq No: 9002
2
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
LONG JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-214-703 Seq No: 9002
3
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D004 0.00 0.00
SHORT JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-213-703 Seq No: 9003
4
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D004 0.00 0.00
SHORT JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-214-703 Seq No: 9003
```

I want to pull several items from this text in a loop. To put in perspective, this text is a purchase order from a customer.

I want to pull the line item, the qty, the part number, description, who drew it, and the due date for the line.

My problem is that the method I am using to get the info doesn't seem like the best option out there. How would one go about this in a more efficient manner?

I plan to loop through each line item(I figure there's a way to loop every 7 lines) and place each piece of data into a variable in a object I will create, and place those objects in a list.

So far I am getting some of the information with little effort but I feel I am doing it in a rather messy way. here is what I came up with this morning:

```
string startString = richTextBox1.Text;
string qty = startString.Substring(6, startString.IndexOf(' '));
int index = startString.IndexOf(' ');
index = startString.IndexOf(' ', index + 1);
string partNumber = startString.Substring(index, 14);
string description = startString.Substring(index+ 25, startString.IndexOf(":"));
```

once I build this list I will place this data into an excel sheet, which I will figure out later(one problem at a time!)

Comment: Do you have an actual problem with memory or performance? Halving runtime for something that takes 10 days to run, or is run million of times per second has a lot bigger impact than halving runtime for something that takes 100ms and is run once a day. So, what is your current performance, how fast do you need it to run, how much data are you processing, and how frequently?

Comment: _"How would one go about this in a more efficient manner?"_ - Somewhat unrelated: One would insist on using a digitally processable format. There are standards for Purchase Order XML out there ...

Comment: You are using `Substring` which is the most efficient way to get parts of a string. So it's not clear to me how you want to optimize it. If you want to make it more failsafe then you have not provided enough information to let us help you since the rules are not clear.

Comment: I agree with JonasH and want to add that in my 40+ years of software development, I have only used what I was confident to be "the best option out there" two or three times.  Good enough is literally good enough.  Don't go looking for problems you don't have.  This seems like a code review request (since I presume it works correctly)  My personal style is to break code into functions that have names that describe what they are doing, eliminate the use of magic numbers, and check for unexpected input (e..g `IndexOf` may return -1).

Comment: I guess what I am trying to figure out is when someone does a substring do they really sit here and do index +24 to get to a position? is there a more elegent way to find my data within the string.

Comment: What do mean by "elegant"? If your data is fixed-size, then indexing is your best horse. Maybe get rid of "magic numbers" for readability, but _that_ won't change runtime.

Comment: the data isn' t a fixed size. a purchase can have 1 line item on it for dozens. Unless you mean each line item, i suppose that is a pretty fixed format.

Comment: Of course you could use `string.Split` instead of `IndexOf`+`Substring`. You might get code which is easier to understand(for example with LINQ). But it will not be more efficient than what you already have. `string.Split` will create a new array with all parts separated by space(even if you only need one), your approach does not need that.

Comment: Thank you for the comments everyone. I will take this all in and give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = @"
1
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
LONG JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-213-703 Seq No: 9002
2
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
LONG JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-214-703 Seq No: 9002
3
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D004 0.00 0.00
SHORT JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-213-703 Seq No: 9003
4
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D004 0.00 0.00
SHORT JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-214-703 Seq No: 9003
";
            Purchas_Order po = new Purchas_Order(input);
            po.Print(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
        }
    }
    public class Purchas_Order
    {
        public static List<Purchas_Order> purchase_orders { get; set; }

        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
        public string partNumber { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string drawing { get; set; }
        public DateTime due { get; set; }
        public string requester { get; set; }
        public string order { get; set; }
        public int seq_num { get; set; }

        public Purchas_Order() { }
        public Purchas_Order(string orders)
        {
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(orders);
            string line = "";
            int index = 0;

            purchase_orders = new List<Purchas_Order>();
            Purchas_Order newOrder = null;
            string[] splitLine;
            string pattern = @"\s*(?'key'[^:]+):\s*(?'value'[^\s]+)";
            MatchCollection matches;
            int lineNumber = 0;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNumber++;
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        switch (index % 7)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                newOrder = new Purchas_Order();
                                purchase_orders.Add(newOrder);
                                newOrder.quantity = int.Parse(line);
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                newOrder.size = line.Trim();
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                newOrder.partNumber = line.Trim();
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                newOrder.description = line.Trim();
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                                newOrder.drawing = splitLine[1].Trim();
                                break;

                            case 5:
                                matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
                                newOrder.due = DateTime.Parse(matches[0].Groups["value"].Value);
                                newOrder.requester = matches[1].Groups["value"].Value.Trim();
                                break;

                            case 6:
                                matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
                                newOrder.order = matches[0].Groups["value"].Value.Trim();
                                newOrder.seq_num = int.Parse(matches[1].Groups["value"].Value);
                                break;


                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Line Number = {0}, Index = {1}, Case = {2}, Line = {3}", lineNumber, index, index % 7, line);
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        public void Print(string filename)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            foreach(Purchas_Order order in Purchas_Order.purchase_orders)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Quantity : {0}", order.quantity);
                writer.WriteLine("Size : {0}", order.size);
                writer.WriteLine("Part Number : {0}", order.partNumber);
                writer.WriteLine("Description : {0}", order.description);
                writer.WriteLine("Drawing : {0}", order.drawing);
                writer.WriteLine("Due : {0}", order.due);
                writer.WriteLine("Requestor : {0}", order.requester);
                writer.WriteLine("Order : {0}", order.order);
                writer.WriteLine("Sequence Number : {0}", order.seq_num);

                writer.WriteLine("");
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
 
}
```

Here is the Regex pattern

```
Regex pattern

s* - One or more spaces

Define Group Key
(?'key'[^:]+)
Matches any characters up to the colon
^ - NOT

: - Match a colon

\s* - One or Mode spaces

Define Group Value
(?'value'[^\s]+)
Matches any characters up to a space
^ - NOT
```

Comment: how would I find info on how this works? I understand we are making a list of purchase orders, and I understand the case switch statements. But im very unclear on the Regular expressions. So far it looks promising going about it this way, however it isn't breaking the string properly and I have no knowledge of regular expressions past my 5 minute google search. So I have little to no chance of actually figuring out how to change this to work.

Comment: The results are going into a static list called purchase_orders.  What string is not being broken properly?  I tested the existing 4 orders.  The only think I didn't break was the line 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00

Comment: to test this, i put a messagebox after the while statement to show the part number of newOrder. It gives some repetive messageboxes that are either blank or show the line you didnt break up. think it shows the blank box 4 times then the unbroken line 4 times, and loops this for i assume 4 times for the 4 line items. ill try out a different variable to see the results as well

Comment: I updated code to add a print method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I got the print statement to work, it now gives error "System.FormatException: 'The string 'NMB' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '0'.'" on the second line of case 5

Comment: I added an exception handler.  These type error are common when parsing text.  You must be using a different input.  Need line with error.  The Date must be different for that line.

Comment: going to try this out. now I am getting unauthorized access to pretty much any folder on my computer when running the app. stay tuned! thanks again for the help

Comment: When reading from a file you need to replace StringReader(string)  with StreamReader(filename)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Regular Expressions. [Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/LRZ571/1)

```
^(?<index>\d)\nEA\n\s(?<quantity>[0-9\.]+)\s(?<partNumber>[0-9A-Z-]+)\s(?<unknown1>[0-9\.]+)\s(?<unknown2>[0-9\.]+)\n(?<partName>[A-Z\s]+)\nDrawing\:\s(?<drawing>[A-Z]+)\nDue\:\s(?<due>[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\sRequester\:\s(?<requester>[A-Z]+)\nOrder\:\s(?<order>[0-9A-Z-]+)\sSeq\sNo\:\s(?<sequence>[0-9]+)$
```

This matches per record:

- Index
- Quantity
- PartNumber
- Unkown1
- Unkown2
- PartName
- Drawing
- Due
- Requester
- Order
- Sequence

you can also wrap this as a record such as:

```
^(?<entry>(?<index>\d)\nEA\n\s(?<quantity>[0-9\.]+)\s(?<partNumber>[0-9A-Z-]+)\s(?<unknown1>[0-9\.]+)\s(?<unknown2>[0-9\.]+)\n(?<partName>[A-Z\s]+)\nDrawing\:\s(?<drawing>[A-Z]+)\nDue\:\s(?<due>[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\sRequester\:\s(?<requester>[A-Z]+)\nOrder\:\s(?<order>[0-9A-Z-]+)\sSeq\sNo\:\s(?<sequence>[0-9]+))$
```

This does the same as the above but groups each sub match.

This matches per record:

- Entry

  - Index
  - Quantity
  - PartNumber
  - Unkown1
  - Unkown2
  - PartName
  - Drawing
  - Due
  - Requester
  - Order
  - Sequence

You can load it like this in C#

can be tested [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dx7gGY)

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String data = @"1
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
LONG JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-213-703 Seq No: 9002
2
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D003 0.00 0.00
LONG JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-214-703 Seq No: 9002
3
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D004 0.00 0.00
SHORT JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-213-703 Seq No: 9003
4
EA
 2.00 2814-212-D004 0.00 0.00
SHORT JACK PAD
Drawing: OPT
Due: 05/19/2023 Requester: NMB
Order: 2843HR-214-703 Seq No: 9003";
        String exprGroup = @"(?<entry>(?<index>\d)\nEA\n\s(?<quantity>[0-9\.]+)\s(?<partNumber>[0-9A-Z-]+)\s(?<unknonw1>[0-9\.]+)\s(?<unknonw2>[0-9\.]+)\n(?<partName>[A-Z\s]+)\nDrawing\:\s(?<drawing>[A-Z]+)\nDue\:\s(?<date>[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\sRequester\:\s(?<requester>[A-Z]+)\nOrder\:\s(?<order>[0-9A-Z-]+)\sSeq\sNo\:\s(?<sequence>[0-9]+))";
        String exprRecord = @"(?<index>\d)\nEA\n\s(?<quantity>[0-9\.]+)\s(?<partNumber>[0-9A-Z-]+)\s(?<unknonw1>[0-9\.]+)\s(?<unknonw2>[0-9\.]+)\n(?<partName>[A-Z\s]+)\nDrawing\:\s(?<drawing>[A-Z]+)\nDue\:\s(?<date>[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\sRequester\:\s(?<requester>[A-Z]+)\nOrder\:\s(?<order>[0-9A-Z-]+)\sSeq\sNo\:\s(?<sequence>[0-9]+)";
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(data, exprGroup);
        
            Console.WriteLine(mc[0]);
        foreach (Match m in mc) {
            MatchCollection mc2 = Regex.Matches(m.Value, exprRecord);
            foreach (Match m2 in mc2) {
                Console.WriteLine(m2.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```